# What is wrong with the sql statement

Tags: mysql

I want to list all the data from a particular table which fulfills a specific criteria.
For example table named 'jobs' which is inner join with the table named 'user'.

```
    SELECT jobs.*,user.* , COUNT( jobs.user_id ) as posted_job 
    FROM jobs
    INNER JOIN user ON user.id = jobs.user_id
    WHERE jobs.user_id =2
    GROUP BY jobs.user_id
```

I want to list all the specific records,but from above statements it showing only one record.Actually I have three records with jobs.user_id =2.

Comment: take out `GROUP BY jobs.user_id`

Comment: @Abhik..tried ..not working.

Comment: can you put sample records from both tables?

Comment: you are taking count(). so it will show only 1 row

Comment: ok I got it its working fn9 without count but I want count of the query along with result..then how will get count of result.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
SELECT j.user_id , COUNT( j.user_id ) as posted_job 
    FROM jobs as j
    JOIN user as u ON u.id = j.user_id
    WHERE j.user_id =2
    GROUP BY j.user_id
```

If want all users count then try below:

```
SELECT j.user_id , COUNT( j.user_id ) as posted_job 
    FROM jobs as j
    JOIN user as u ON u.id = j.user_id
    GROUP BY j.user_id
```

If you want to get listing along with count then try below:

```
SELECT 
j.*,u.posted_job 
FROM jobs AS j
JOIN
(SELECT j.user_id , COUNT( j.user_id ) AS posted_job 
    FROM jobs AS j
    JOIN USER AS u ON u.id = j.user_id
    WHERE j.user_id =2
    GROUP BY j.user_id) AS u
ON u.user_id=j.user_id 
WHERE j.user_id=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are doing `COUNT( jobs.user_id )`  and use of count will restrict the result set to one row in a sigle query

Since you are doing query on a single user_id so count does not make sense here, the total number of rows will be the count in this case.

So you may need to do as

```
SELECT jobs.*,user.* 
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = jobs.user_id
WHERE jobs.user_id =2
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65d75/4)**

Use of aggregate function or count is suitable when you want to see the data for all the users in your case so the following

```
SELECT jobs.*,user.*,count(jobs.user_id) as total 
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = jobs.user_id
group by jobs.user_id
```

Will list the count of jobs per user

Comment: Counting and listing does not go together as per your requirement. Only in the 2nd case its possible. You may need to use your server side script to get the total rows after executing the query.